# Typescript monad for data being loaded

Tags: functional-programming, error-handling, typescript, type-safety, monads

I have been struggling to make typescript happy about the types.
I am pulling data from our backend API and I wanted to give context to the data. Basically it is a monad with 4 shapes:

- Initial (nothing)
- Loading (maybe with percent?)
- Failed (maybe with error?)
- Loaded(with the actual value).

I want it to have the usual `.of()`, `.map()`, `.chain()` functions that you would expect in a monadic data structure.

After trying many different ways (with average success). I came up with this implementation:

```
type Kind = 'initial' | 'loading' | 'loaded' | 'failed'
type DefaultError = any
export class Data<T, E = DefaultError> {
  private constructor(
    public readonly kind: Kind,
    public readonly data: T | undefined,
    private readonly error: E | undefined,
    private readonly percent: number | undefined,
  ) {}

  static initial<T, E>() {
    return new Data<T, E>('initial', undefined, undefined, undefined)
  }

  static loading<T, E>(percent?: number) {
    return new Data<T, E>('loading', undefined, undefined, percent)
  }

  static failed<T, E>(error?: E) {
    return new Data<T, E>('failed', undefined, error, undefined)
  }

  static loaded<T, E>(value: T) {
    return new Data<T, E>('loaded', value, undefined, undefined)
  }

  static orInitial<T, E>(value: Data<T, E> | undefined) {
    if (value === undefined) {
      return Data.initial<T, E>()
    }
    return value
  }

  static getData<T, E>(wrapped: Data<T, E>) {
    return wrapped.data
  }

  static getDataOrElse<T, E>(defaultValue: T) {
    return function(wrapped: Data<T, E>) {
      return wrapped.kind === 'loaded' ? wrapped.data! : defaultValue
    }
  }

  join() {
    return this.data!
  }

  map<R>(f: (wrapped: T) => R): Data<R, E> {
    switch (this.kind) {
      case 'loaded':
        return Data.loaded(f(this.data!))
      case 'loading':
        return Data.loading()
      case 'failed':
        return Data.failed(this.error)
      case 'initial':
        return Data.initial()
    }
  }




  flatMap<R, E>(f: (wrapped: T) => Data<R, E>): Data<R, E> {
    switch (this.kind) {
      case 'loaded':
        return f(this.data!)
      case 'loading':
        return Data.loading<R,E>()
      case 'failed':
        return Data.failed<R,E>((this.error as unknown) as E)
      case 'initial':
        return Data.initial<R,E>()
    }
  }

  match<O1, O2, O3, O4>({
    initial,
    loaded,
    loading,
    failed,
  }: {
    initial: () => O1
    loaded: (value?: T) => O2
    loading: (percent?: number) => O3
    failed: (error?: E) => O4
  }) {
    switch (this.kind) {
      case 'loaded':
        return loaded(this.data!)
      case 'loading':
        return loading(this.percent)
      case 'failed':
        return failed(this.error)
      case 'initial':
        return initial()
    }
  }

  static isInitial<T, E>(wrapped: Data<T, E>): wrapped is Data<T, E> & { kind: 'initial' } {
    return wrapped.kind === 'initial'
  }

  static isLoading<T, E>(wrapped: Data<T, E>): wrapped is Data<T, E> & { kind: 'loading'; percent?: number } {
    return wrapped.kind === 'loading'
  }

  static isFailed<T, E>(wrapped: Data<T, E>): wrapped is Data<T, E> & { kind: 'failed'; error?: E } {
    return wrapped.kind === 'failed'
  }

  static isLoaded<T, E>(wrapped: Data<T, E>): wrapped is Data<T, E> & { kind: 'loaded'; data: T } {
    return wrapped.kind === 'loaded'
  }

  isInitial(): this is { kind: 'initial' } {
    return this.kind === 'initial'
  }

  isLoading(): this is { kind: 'loading'; percent?: number } {
    return this.kind === 'loading'
  }

  isFailed(): this is { kind: 'failed'; error?: E } {
    return this.kind === 'failed'
  }

  isLoaded(): this is { kind: 'loaded'; data: T } {
    return this.kind === 'loaded'
  }

  getValueOrElse(defaultValue: T) {
    return this.kind === 'loaded' ? this.data : defaultValue
  }

  getPercentOrElse(defaultPercent: number) {
    return this.kind === 'loading' ? this.percent : defaultPercent
  }

  getErrorOrElse(defaultError: E) {
    return this.kind === 'failed' ? this.error : defaultError
  }
}
```

I am not too happy with it. Mainly because I have to do `null` checks on error, value, percent fields. I wanted to have some sort of a tagged union type but I couldn't make it work. Also the `isLoaded()` type guard doesn't seem to really work when doing something like this:

```
// I cast to make typescript forget about the fact that the data is loaded
const data:Data<number> = Data.loaded(3) as any as Data<number>

data.data // <-- says number | undefined, but I would really prefer it not even allowing me to access the field

if(data.isLoaded()) {
  data.data // <-- number, so that is correct because it know the data is loaded
}

const dataArray: Data<number>[] = [Data.failed(), Data.loaded(2)]

dataArray.filter(Data.isLoaded)
.map(Data.getData)
.map(x => x) // <-- number or undefined, that shouldn't happen

dataArray.filter(Data.isLoaded)
.map(x => x.data)
.map(x => x) // <-- number but not undefined?
```

How can I best modify it and have strong typing with it?

This is a crucial part in our project because we use it everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! IMHO your question title can and should be improved. Be sure to check [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially *Titling your question* in the Help Center.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding, what is the point of the `initial` state? If this is wrapping backend data it seems like it should only ever be loading, loaded, or failed. What does `initial` signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is Code Review, and not Stack Overflow where you'd just want an answer... first a couple comments on your code:

1. First off, this is not a monad with 4 shapes. This is a monad with 6 shapes. "maybe with" indicates you have more than one shape. This is a *lot* of shapes to keep track of with a single class. The data class is really: `Maybe<OneOf<Maybe<Error>, Maybe<Percent>, Data>>`... and that's bound to be messy.
2. If you declare the type of the variable, TypeScript will not infer a more specific type. There's no cast needed here.

   ```
   // I cast to make typescript forget about the fact that the data is loaded
   const data: Data<number> = Data.loaded(3) as any as Data<number>
   ```
3. Don't lie to the compiler. The `flatMap` implementation has:

   ```
   case 'failed':
       return Data.failed<R, E>((this.error as unknown) as E);
   ```

   This can (and likely will) result in an error which isn't correct. You should either return `Data<R, E | E2>` or force the callback to return `Data<R, E>` where `E` is the same as the container.
4. Does it make sense to have a `Data<Data<number, Error>, Error>`? I don't think it does... this is the same problem that the authors of the `Promise` spec had to solve, and they decided to solve it by breaking the monad laws. It may make sense to do the same. `Data` seems conceptually closer to `Promise` than `Either` to me.
5. Since you have the `join` accessor, I would make `data` private. You can then use the `this` parameter to force an error if TS doesn't *know* that there is data present.

   ```
   static getData<T, E>(wrapped: Data<T, E> & { kind: "loaded", data: T }) {
       return wrapped.join();
   }

   join(this: { data: T }) {
       return this.data;
   }
   ```
6. I would expect the `get*OrElse` functions to return `NonNullable` types. When I call `getPercentOrElse(5)` I'd expect to receive a number, but I still might get `undefined`.
7. It might be worth making a `const enum DataState { initial, loading, loaded, failed }` to avoid typing strings everywhere. As `const enum`s are inlined by the compiler, there will be no performance loss (and you can still use strings if you like).

---

Here's one possible fix for your `Data.getData` function. I assume you don't want it to work unless you know `Data<T, E>` is actually `loaded`, so make that explicit, and your `number | undefined` issue goes away.

```
static getData<T, E>(wrapped: Data<T, E> & { kind: "loaded", data: T }) {
    wrapped.data;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use conditional types to optionally include `undefined` in the return type, but this would be messier.

---

Putting this last as it is more of a frame challenge than a review of your code:

I believe the `Data` class does too much. I'd rather deal with multiple less complicated objects.

What is the problem we are trying to solve here? We are pulling data from a back end API. This API might return the data we want, an error, or the network response itself might error. Thus, we have `Either<NetworkError | APIError, Data>`.

Now, before the request resolves (either with data or an error) we will be in a loading state. We *could* overload our `Either<NetworkError | APIError, Data>` with another possible state, or we could let our caller deal with that, and only call this class once a concrete result is available.

I prefer the second option. This will be achieved with a `Request` which will always have a "percent" completion (just 0 if not updated by the user) and a result. For convenience, a `Request` (unlike `Either`) will be mutable. Also for convenience, it will include the `Left` side of an `Either` result as its own `Error` state.

If you might not have actually made a request yet, we might not have a percent completion or a result. Instead of adding an "initial" state, I'll just wrap cases which require this in `Maybe`.

With these changes, here's what a simple app that makes an API request when the user clicks a button and displays the result could look like.

```
// This would be nicer to do with a React component
let state: Maybe<Request<string, string>> = Maybe.nothing();

const button = document.querySelector('button')!;
const result = document.querySelector('#result') as HTMLDivElement;
function render() {
    state.match({
        nothing() {
            button.hidden = false;
            result.hidden = true;
        },
        just(request) {
            button.hidden = true;
            result.hidden = false;

            request.match({
                loading(percent) {
                    result.textContent = `Loading: ${percent * 100}%`;
                },
                error(error) {
                    result.textContent = `ERROR: ${error}`;
                },
                result(data) {
                    result.textContent = data;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

// Todo
function makeResponse(): Request<string, string> {}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    state = Maybe.just(makeResponse());
    render();
});

render();
```

I don't actually need fully fleshed out `Maybe` and `Either` classes, so here's what I'll use:

```
export class Maybe<T> {
    static nothing<T>() { return new Maybe<T>(undefined) }
    static just<T>(value?: T) { return new Maybe(value) }

    private constructor(private value?: T) {}

    match<A, B>({ nothing, just }: {
        nothing: () => A,
        just: (value: T) => B
    }): A | B {
        return this.value == null ? nothing() : just(this.value)
    }
}

// It isn't safe to use `undefined` as an empty signal since we could have `Either<undefined, number>`
// Technically this applies to Maybe<T> as well, but I find it useful to allow undefined to signal nothing.
const EMPTY: unique symbol = Symbol()
type Empty = typeof EMPTY

export class Either<Left, Right> {
    private constructor(private data: [Left, Empty] | [Empty, Right]) {}

    static left<Left = unknown, Right = unknown>(value: Left): Either<Left, Right> {
        return new Either<Left, Right>([value, EMPTY]);
    }

    static right<Left = unknown, Right = unknown>(value: Right): Either<Left, Right> {
        return new Either<Left, Right>([EMPTY, value]);
    }

    match<T>(left: (left: Left) => T, right: (right: Right) => T) {
        return this.data[0] !== EMPTY ?
            left(this.data[0]) :
            right(this.data[1] as Right) // Unfortunately TS isn't smart enough to infer
    }
}
```

Now to implement our `Request`... it is surprisingly easy to model! This is an indication that the design is a good idea, since good design should make it easy to achieve our goals.

```
import { Either } from "./either";

export class Request<TData, TError = unknown> {
    private constructor(private percent: number, private data: Either<TError, TData> | undefined) {}

    static incomplete() {
        return new Request(0, undefined);
    }

    match<T>({ loading, error, result }: {
        loading: (percent: number) => T,
        error: (error: TError) => T,
        result: (result: TData) => T
    }) {
        if (this.data === undefined) {
            return loading(this.percent);
        }
        return this.data.match(error, result);
    }

    setPercent(percent: number) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    setResult(result: TData) {
        this.data = Either.right(result);
    }

    setError(error: TError) {
        this.data = Either.left(error);
    }
}
```

With everything at once, here's our little demo app.

```
class Maybe<T> {
    static nothing<T>() { return new Maybe<T>(undefined) }
    static just<T>(value?: T) { return new Maybe(value) }

    private constructor(private value?: T) {}

    match<A, B>({ nothing, just }: {
        nothing: () => A,
        just: (value: T) => B
    }): A | B {
        return this.value == null ? nothing() : just(this.value)
    }
}

const EMPTY: unique symbol = Symbol()
type Empty = typeof EMPTY

class Either<Left, Right> {
    private constructor(private data: [Left, Empty] | [Empty, Right]) {}

    static left<Left = unknown, Right = unknown>(value: Left): Either<Left, Right> {
        return new Either<Left, Right>([value, EMPTY]);
    }

    static right<Left = unknown, Right = unknown>(value: Right): Either<Left, Right> {
        return new Either<Left, Right>([EMPTY, value]);
    }

    match<T>(left: (left: Left) => T, right: (right: Right) => T) {
        return this.data[0] !== EMPTY ?
            left(this.data[0]) :
            right(this.data[1] as Right); // Unfortunately TS isn't smart enough to infer
    }
}

class Request<TData, TError = unknown> {
    private constructor(private percent: number, private data: Either<TError, TData> | undefined) {}

    static incomplete<TData, TError>() {
        return new Request<TData, TError>(0, undefined);
    }

    match<T>({ loading, error, result }: {
        loading: (percent: number) => T,
        error: (error: TError) => T,
        result: (result: TData) => T
    }) {
        if (this.data === undefined) {
            return loading(this.percent);
        }
        return this.data.match(error, result);
    }

    setPercent(percent: number) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    setResult(result: TData) {
        this.data = Either.right(result);
    }

    setError(error: TError) {
        this.data = Either.left(error);
    }
}

// This would be nicer to do with a React component
let state: Maybe<Request<string, string>> = Maybe.nothing();

const button = document.querySelector('button')!;
const result = document.querySelector('#result') as HTMLDivElement;
function render() {
    state.match({
        nothing() {
            button.hidden = false;
            result.hidden = true;
        },
        just(request) {
            button.hidden = true;
            result.hidden = false;

            request.match({
                loading(percent) {
                    result.textContent = `Loading: ${percent * 100}%`;
                },
                error(error) {
                    result.textContent = `ERROR: ${error}`;
                },
                result(data) {
                    result.textContent = data;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function makeResponse(): Request<string, string> {
    const response = Request.incomplete<string, string>();
    setTimeout(function () {
        response.setPercent(.99);
        render();
    }, 500)
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            response.setResult('Got a result!')
        } else {
            response.setError('Got an error!')
        }
        render();
    }, 2000)
    return response;
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    state = Maybe.just(makeResponse());
    render();
});

render();
```

And here's the app with the compiled source.

```js
class Maybe {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    static nothing() { return new Maybe(undefined); }
    static just(value) { return new Maybe(value); }
    match({ nothing, just }) {
        return this.value == null ? nothing() : just(this.value);
    }
}
const EMPTY = Symbol();
class Either {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    static left(value) {
        return new Either([value, EMPTY]);
    }
    static right(value) {
        return new Either([EMPTY, value]);
    }
    match(left, right) {
        return this.data[0] !== EMPTY ?
            left(this.data[0]) :
            right(this.data[1]);
    }
}
class Request {
    constructor(percent, data) {
        this.percent = percent;
        this.data = data;
    }
    static incomplete() {
        return new Request(0, undefined);
    }
    match({ loading, error, result }) {
        if (this.data === undefined) {
            return loading(this.percent);
        }
        return this.data.match(error, result);
    }
    setPercent(percent) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }
    setResult(result) {
        this.data = Either.right(result);
    }
    setError(error) {
        this.data = Either.left(error);
    }
}
let state = Maybe.nothing();
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
function render() {
    state.match({
        nothing() {
            button.hidden = false;
            result.hidden = true;
        },
        just(request) {
            button.hidden = true;
            result.hidden = false;
            request.match({
                loading(percent) {
                    result.textContent = `Loading: ${percent * 100}%`;
                },
                error(error) {
                    result.textContent = `ERROR: ${error}`;
                },
                result(data) {
                    result.textContent = data;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
function makeResponse() {
    const response = Request.incomplete();
    setTimeout(function () {
        response.setPercent(.99);
        render();
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            response.setResult('Got a result!');
        }
        else {
            response.setError('Got an error!');
        }
        render();
    }, 2000);
    return response;
}
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    state = Maybe.just(makeResponse());
    render();
});
render();
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```